# QR-Code prefixed or not?

Tags: myetherwallet, qrcode

should I put the prefix `ethereum:` before the address when creating a QR-Code ?

When I read a QR-Code generated by https://www.myetherwallet.com, the prefix is missing.

But I found conflicting informations like https://jibrelnetwork.github.io/ethereum-qr-code/demo-simple.html

If I can omit it, what is it purpose on bitcoin or litecoin addresses per example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ethereum-qr-code` follows [EIP 67](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67), which is still open, so not quite a standard. Notice that it gives more than just an address. (It supports parameters too.) Consider reading that full comment thread to see what debate exists around it.

If you just need to communicate an address, a QR code with just the address seems fine. (I believe that's MyEtherWallet's use case.) If you're aiming for a future "scan this QR code to buy this" scenario, you'll need to be able to specify a price and currency, hence EIP 67.